# super().method() vs Parent.method()

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, abstract-class

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        print('init parent')
    def hithere(self):
        print('hey there')
        print(self.x)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        super().hithere()

child = Child(3)
```

Here I have a Parent class and a child class which inherets from the parent. 
Why do I need super() If I can always do the same thing by replacing it with the name of the parent class im inhereting:

```
class Parent():
    def __init__(self, x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        print('init parent')
    def hithere(self):
        print('hey there')
        print(self.x)

class Child(Parent):
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
        Parent.hithere(self)

child = Child(3)
```

which does the same thing.

My second question is it correct to say that abstract classes can't have atributes? If Parent was an abstract class, then whenever one of it's methods calls for self like hithere(self), I need to pass it back with super().method(self). So those attributes are actually Child's attributes, which just so happen to have the same attribut names as the parent class to be used.

Comment: abstract classes can have attributes, those are the attributes that are common with the child classes. For example, if you were building a game, you may have a `Character` class which is abstract, and contains `name`, and `health`, both are attributes of `Character` and what ever subclass inherits `Character`, so for example, `Wizard`. You can have an abstract method in `Character` called `attack()` and every subclass would be responsible for implementing it's own behaviour.

Comment: `super()` is the correct way to handle passing arguments from the child class to the parent class, and if you use multiple inheritance, you'll need to use `super()` to build co-operative classes.

Comment: @nsonline I think your answer is the best. If you made your comments into questions I'll accept your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is one and the same thing, but you should you `super()` because:

In future, if you want to change the name of the parent class, then you don't have to change the name for every instance.

For e.g.

```
Parent.hithere(self)
Parent.hithere1(self)
Parent.hithere2(self)
```

Now if you change the name of your parent class, then you would have to change the name `Parent` for every instance. This would not be the case, if you would do:

```
super().hithere1()
super().hithere2()
super().hithere3()
```

I think your second question is ambiguous, but you can read more about the abstract class [here](https://www.python-course.eu/python3_abstract_classes.php).

Answer (score 0):

You almost always want to use `self.foo()`, unless you're writing a `Child.foo` method that overwrites `Parent.foo`.

If you later write a `Child.hithere` method, your current code won't use it, which is frequently not what you want.